# React + Facebook api conversion

Tags: reactjs, facebook-conversions-api

Since yesterday I have been struggling with a problem regarding the Facebook conversion API. I have a website (frontend only) and I would like to connect Facebook API Conversion to my website but I have no idea how to do it. There are plenty of videos on the Internet, but they all concern CMS systems. Is it possible for me to connect this in a React application? For example, in the App.js component?